# Leaflet - enable/disable control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I would like to ask you if there is some way how to disable/enable [routing plugin](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine)

The control is added into the leaflet in this way:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
waypoints: [
    L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
    L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
]
}).addTo(map);
```

Does anybody have an idea how to dynamically disable/enable this control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `L.Routing.Control` extends `L.Routing.Itinerary` which [implements](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-itinerary) show() and hide() methods. So you should be able to do something like this:

```
var routeControl = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
]
}).addTo(map);

//.. Some other code ..

if(hide)
   routeControl.hide();
else
   routeControl.show();
```